# select2 strange behavior when allowClear: true

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have selector:

```
view.find('.entitySelector').select2({
    data       : source.listing().map(source.toDropdown(['id', 'title'])),
    allowClear : true,
    placeholder: "bla bla"
});
```

When selector defined as

```
<select name="entity_id" class="form-control entitySelector">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

all well work. And at this time the select2 dot showing blank option (why?).

But, if selector defined as

```
<select name="entity_id" class="form-control entitySelector">
</select>
```

this `allowClear : true` not working as expected, and showing always selected first item of the select2's data.

I tried with a different set of source data.
Why is this happening?